# Unhandled exception: Error creating account

Tags: mysql, admin

I'm trying to set up a database with MySQL and this error keeps popping up: `Unhandled exception: Error creating account blank@blank. Error executing 'Access denied; you need (at least one of)the create user privileges for this operation.` 
I'm wondering if and how I can change my own account settings so that I'll be able to add new users again and be able to do other things. The program I'm currently using for this is MySQL workbench and I recently put the server onto a Microsoft web-matrix website. I'm not completely sure if that can cause any odd effects but I just want to be safe. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new connection in MySQL workbench with user root. Logon with that user in MySQL workbench and go to a Query window. Assuming you want to access everything and have all privileges, issue the following SQL statement. Replace 'you' with your username.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'you'@localhost;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'you'@'%';
```

That will give you pretty much everything.

Here is the [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html)

Comment: you're welcome. there is more in the documentation. I added a link to my answer